# How to set context from inside an event handler (using the new ReactJs context API)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a ReactJS select where the user chooses an option related to an application version. I want to set an application context varible to the choosen option id.

**AppContext.js:**

```
export const AppContext = React.createContext({
  versions: null,
  currentVersion: null
});
```

**VersionChooser.js (component):**

```
class VersionChooser extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        context: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    handleSelectChange = event => {
        let context = {
          currentVersion: event.target.value
        }
          /////////// WHAT TO DO HERE TO SET CONTEXT ///////////
          <AppContext.Provider value={context}>
          </AppContext.Provider>
    };

    render = () => {

        let options = this.props.context.versions.map(item => {
            return (
                <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                    {item.name}
                </option>
            );
        });

        return (
                <select value={this.props.context.currentVersion} onChange={this.handleSelectChange}>
                    {options}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default VersionChooser;
```

I need help to set the context´s `currentVersion` variable inside my `handleSelectChange` handler (repair that context has 2 variables and I just want to set one of them).

Comment: Add `AppContext.Provider` and `AppContext.Consumer` code.